# System.reactive cross thread operation absurdity

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, observablecollection, system.reactive

I'm trying to get a very simple example of outputting a subscribed sequence to a textbox to work, as you'd expect there's no problem doing it in a console application.

I've tried a dozen different variations of invoke, all of which throw the same cross thread hissy fit.

I read that ObserveOnDispatcher might do the job? but I can't find that anywhere. I've tried ObserveOn as you can see in the following code, but again the same problem.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var source = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Timestamp();

    source.ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread).Subscribe(x => textBox1.AppendText(x.Value.ToString()));
}
```

I don't understand why the following works fine;

```
source.Subscribe(x => MessageBox.Show(x.Value + " - " + x.Timestamp));
```

Yet writing those some values to a textbox requires a tantrum.

Any ideas?

Comment: tag your question with wpf/winforms

Comment: I found [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74f00198-8abe-4d5d-b1d3-793b84636258/observeon-doesnt-observe-on-requested-thread) on the MSDN forum which should answer your question.

Comment: This is duplicate of similar issues where a control cannot be updated from a worker thread. However, as we do not know if you are using WPF Or WinForms it is impossible to point you to the right answer.

Comment: "This is duplicate of similar issues where a control cannot be updated from a worker thread" - It isn't though, because normally invoke would work, but it doesn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74f00198-8abe-4d5d-b1d3-793b84636258/observeon-doesnt-observe-on-requested-thread) on the MSDN forum using the [`CurrentThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.concurrency.scheduler.currentthread%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) scheduler

> [...] doesn't mean the thread on which the query was created, it means the current thread on which the query is executing.  In this respect, it's similar to the Immediate scheduler.  The difference is that the CurrentThread scheduler uses a single queue for all scheduled actions to support single-threaded cooperative multitasking, whereas the Immediate scheduler executes a scheduled action immediately, regardless of whether a previously scheduled action is still executing.

There are specialized methods for observing on the UI threads if you use WPF or Windows Forms: [`ObserveOnDispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211843%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and [`ObserveOn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244287%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, that works in both cases if you use `SynchronizationContext.Current` as this will return a special version if you're on a UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a Scheduler into `Observable.Timer`:

```
var source = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), DispatcherScheduler.Current).Timestamp();
```

`Observable.Timer` uses the Taskpool by default. In general, if an operator lets you specify a scheduler, you should do it.